# How to use single .env file for full stack React + Node app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, environment-variables, .env

I'm building my first full stack app with React and Node. The project has a root directory, with a client folder (for the React subproject) and a server folder (for the Node subproject). I recently migrated the React project from create-react-app to Vite.

I want both the frontend and backend to be able to read the server port, the client port, and the base URL (localhost for now) from a single .env file in the root directory of the entire project to avoid hardcoding these values.

It seems like having two separate .env files for the client and server is simple, as Vite can read from a .env file put in the client directory and Node can read from a .env file put in the server directory.

How can I get the project to work with one .env file in the root directory? Is it good/standard practice to have one .env file instead of two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a messy solution, perhaps someone can suggest something cleaner.

1. To dynamically set the port in my vite.config file, I wrote the following code:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";

export default ({ mode }) => {
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, path.resolve(__dirname, "../")) };
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    envDir: "../",
    server: {
      port: process.env.VITE_CLIENT_PORT,
    }
  })
}
```

2. I also added the `envDir` attribute to the file (as seen above) to configure Vite/React to read environment variables from the root directory rather than the client directory.
3. Now, in my react project, I can use environment variables like so: `import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_PORT`
4. To use the env variables in my Node project, I can use dotenv like so (while also configuring the .env path):

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' });
const app = express();

app.listen(process.env.VITE_SERVER_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${process.env.VITE_SERVER_PORT}`);
})
```